# Dart: Adding objects made from custom classes to database

Tags: database, flutter, dart, object, oop

i want to set up an editor, where users can create "packs", which are like small books with varying content on each page. Thes Packs are comprised of some data, and pages. Pages have page items, which have their own data and so on.
I modeled this logic as Classes, and am now wondering, as I don't know that much yet about classes and saving to databases, how do I save an object of a pack to my DB? (SQL or NOSQL).
I thought about turning the packs into jsons, but how would i achieve that while keeping the classes?

Here is a screenshot of my code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a toJson function for all your classes and use `jsonEncode(className)`

example -> [link](https://www.bezkoder.com/dart-flutter-convert-object-to-json-string/)